# Use a wraped variable in the type() function. Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to save a string with:

```
        cy.get('#accessInfoText').invoke('text').then($wholeText => {
            let pattern = /(?<=code: ).{10}/i;
            let number = $wholeText.match(pattern);
            cy.wrap(number).as('accessCode');
            cy.log(number);                           // AsTE5sOlJU 
        });
```

Later on, in the test, I need it to type it into an input field:

```
     cy.get('@accessCode').then(code => {
            cy.log(code);                           // [AsTE5sOlJU] 
            cy.followLabel('Access code').type(code)
        });
```

And my problem is that cypress converts it to an object. Which is not accepted by the .type function.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `let number = $wholeText.match(pattern);` returns an array of all matches, even if you only have one.

Try

```js
let number = $wholeText.match(pattern)[0];  // take first match only
```

If there's a possibility that there's no matches, you would need to expand it to avoid a runtime error.

```js
const matches = $wholeText.match(pattern)
const number = matches.length ? matches[0] : null
```

Comment: Ah, thanks that was it. Kinda confusing why the Cypress error was so nonspecific.